# Data List itemCommand function is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, datalist, itemcommand

I've tried to create a datalist with itemcommand function altough it seems that the program doesn't get into the function of the itemcommand for some reason.

**aspx**

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" OnItemCommand="DataList1_ItemCommand" DataKeyField="jobID">
    <ItemTemplate>
       <div class="jobContainer">
          <div class="jobDetails">
             <span class="jobName"><%# Eval("jobName") %></span><br /> 
             <hr class="style13">
             <a class="Details">    <b>Requirments: </b><span ><%# Eval("jobRequirments") %> WPM</span>   </a> 
             <a class="Details">  <b>Salary: </b><span ><%# Eval("jobSalary")%> Shekel per hour</span>  </a>
              
             <a class="Details">   <b>City: </b><span ><%# Eval("jobCity")%></span> 
              <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CommandName="Details" Text="Show Details" />


        </div>
      </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // getjobs returns a dataset
    Service.Service a = new Service.Service();
    DataList1.DataSource = a.getjobs();
    DataList1.DataBind();
}

protected void DataList1_ItemCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Details")
    {
        Response.Redirect("Home.aspx");

    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you bind your datalist, in PageLoad?

Comment: Yes. I updated it. You can see it now.

Comment: The datalist itself works ok and i can see the data in it. The only problem is that the button is refrshing the page and not doing anything. (not getting into the itemcommand funciton)

Comment: See my answer, you need to change your Page_Load, it should solve your problem.

Comment: Yes. It's working now. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you are having an issue with `Page.IsPostBack`, so make sure that you bind your DataList when Page is not `PostBack` in `Page_Load` as following:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (!IsPostBack) 
   {
        //Bind your DataList
        Service.Service a = new Service.Service();
        DataList1.DataSource = a.getjobs();
        DataList1.DataBind();
   }
}
```

See more info about [`Page.IsPostBack`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.page.ispostback)